# How to reject string and double inputs?

Tags: java

Why doesn't the following code reject string and double inputs?
How can I change it so it does?

```
int option;

do {
    System.out.printf("Welcome %s, select an option\n", theUser.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("1: Show previous transactions");
    System.out.println("2: Withdraw");
    System.out.println("3: Deposit");
    System.out.println("4: Transfer");
    System.out.println("5: Exit");
    System.out.print("\nEnter Option: ");
    option = input.nextInt();

    if (option != 1 && option != 2  && option != 3 && option != 4 && option != 5){
        System.out.println("\nError. Please choose a valid number");
    }
} while(option !=  1 && option  != 2  && option  != 3 && option  != 4 && option  != 5);
```

Comment: For some reason the rest of my program doesn't like it when I use | | :(

Answer (score 3):

You could make a method to get an integer and checking that it really is one like this

```
private int getOption() {
    int option;
    try {
      option = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("This was not valid input... " + scanner.next());
      return getOption();
    }
    return option;
}
```

You could also shrink your if block by using

```
if(option < 0 || option > 5)
```

Comment: Should call `nextLine()` in the `catch` block to clear the invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Other than triggering an Exception, you can also use a bit of regular expression to check input is only 1 to 5:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
do{
    System.out.print("Enter option (1-5): ");
    input = scn.nextLine();
    if(!input.matches("[1-5]+"))
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter only 1 - 5");
}while(!input.matches("[1-5]+"));

//int option = Integer.parseInt(input);  //if you need option to be an integer
```

---

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
Enter option (1-5): 3.3
Invalid input, please enter only 1 - 5
Enter option (1-5): 6
Invalid input, please enter only 1 - 5
Enter option (1-5): abc def
Invalid input, please enter only 1 - 5
Enter option (1-5): 
Invalid input, please enter only 1 - 5
Enter option (1-5): 77
Invalid input, please enter only 1 - 5
Enter option (1-5): 3

Process completed.
```

Since I am only strictly matching values from 1 to 5, it blocks off any other inputs such as

- Strings
- Empty inputs
- Decimal values
- Numbers outside the range (`<1` and `>5`).